# Installing a package on a Server using Chef no internet

Tags: ruby, windows, powershell, server, chef-infra

I was wondering if there is a way to install the Management Framewok 5.0 in a server which will have intranet connectivity but no internet to anything else outside the system using a Chef cookbook.

What I had in mind was sort of like sending the files directly to the server from my local machine without having the server download it from the internet. 
The way i'm doing it right now requires the server to get it from the microsoft website. :

```html
# Create installs directory to house downloads
directory 'c:/installs' do
end

# Install Windows Management Framework 5.0
remote_file "c:/installs/Windows-Management-Framework-5.0-2k12R2.msu" do
  source "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717507"
end

# Executes the MSU
execute "c:/installs/Windows-Management-Framework-5.0-2k12R2.msu /quiet" do
  action :nothing
  subscribes :run, resources(:remote_file => "c:/installs/Windows-Management-Framework-5.0-2k12R2.msu")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a specific feature of Chef. We have the `cookbook_file` resource to allow distributing files alongside the cookbook, but using it for installers like this quickly becomes hard to manage. As always when making air-gapped environments, you'll probably have to build your own mirror server and download from that.

Comment: Thanks, for the time been I will use the `cookbook_file`. And try to keep it neat.

Comment: Just don't say we didn't warn ya'.